# WPF Combobox how to display value in LIST Collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a List collection that when it is assigned has a collection of type short numbers. However how do I display the numbers on a WPF ComboBox?

I usually use the DisplayMemberPath property in XAML, but I cannot state a property because it isn't my own collection. (Such as List(T)....)

The XAML

```
<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
     ItemsSource="{Binding TheList}"
     // This is wrong of course
     DisplayMemberPath="."
```

C#

```
public List<short> TheList
{
   get
   {
      return m_ListSID;
   }
   set
   {
      m_ListSID = value;
   }
 }
```

Any help would be grateful.

**EDIT**

Utter silliness...All answers are of course true and makes sense, it was just due that I forgot to trigger the update source for the Collection

```
ItemsSource="{Binding TheList, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Apologises

Thanks

Comment: Short is a C# primitive type, I never created it

Comment: As a better coding practices, collections should be readonly properties and initialized in the get part of property when backup property is null.

Answer (score 1):

[`DisplayMemberPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is not needed here

```
<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left"  ItemsSource="{Binding TheList}" DisplayMemberPath="" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have any `DisplayMemberPath`
This is sufficient:

```
<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding TheList}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't set `DisplayMemberPath` at all and `short` should be converted to `string`

```
<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding TheList}"/>
```

if no template is provided by default WPF will call `ToString()` on an item.

**EDIT**

You can find more details on how display content is created on the [`ContentPresenter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter.aspx) MSDN page